# Moderation request: Make [user] a synonym of [users]

Tags: support, status-completed, users, meta, moderation-request

Please make [user](/questions/tagged/user) a synonym of [users](/questions/tagged/users).
I [proposed a synonym](https://stackapps.com/tags/users/synonyms) but there aren't enough high-rep users active here for that mechanism to work.

Currently*:

- [user](/questions/tagged/user) has 5 questions, no tag wiki and no tag excerpt/blurb.
- [users](/questions/tagged/users) has 47 questions, and an acceptable tag excerpt/blurb.

* I will be hand-retagging those 5 questions immediately after posting this.

---

<sub>Note to newer users: [Stack Apps is its own meta site.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/60099/148310)</sub>